# High data usage by Avast

Tags: proxy, anti-virus, avast

I migrated from Sophos to Avast because Sophos was downloading and uploading 2 GB per day (see [High data usage by Sophos Home](https://superuser.com/questions/1483510/high-data-usage-by-sophos-home)). But avast has the same problem. Here is the output of `nettop` on three different days:

```
$ nettop -P
                    interface  state  bytes_in     bytes_out   rx_dupe    rx_ooo     re-tx
...
com.avast.proxy.684                   1480 MiB      1469 MiB   434 KiB    84 MiB   431 KiB
...
com.avast.proxy.846                   1985 MiB      2008 MiB  5962 KiB    40 MiB    52 MiB
...
com.avast.proxy.745                   2159 MiB      2141 MiB  2201 KiB   220 MiB  1079 KiB
```

I get the same high usage on that process whether or not I am using a VPN from avast (SecureLine).

What is the `com.avast.proxy` process and why does it use such high data? What antivirus for `macOS` do people use on a limited data allowance?

Comment: Have you contacted Avast and/or Sophos support?  Based on the name of the connection, what I suspect might be happening, is all your traffic is going through a proxy.

Comment: Avast and Sophos reserve technical support for paid subscriptions. I found [this thread on the Avast forums](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=187795.msg1321462#msg1321462) mentioning that all traffic is double-counted because of the WebShield. I will experiment with and without it for several days and see if it makes a difference. I found nothing for Sophos on the [forum for Sophos Home](https://support.home.sophos.com/hc/en-us) or [the free stuff forum](https://community.sophos.com/products/free-antivirus-tools-for-desktops/) for searches on "SophosWebIntell" nor "massive upload".

Comment: Supposing that those high numbers are traffic going through a proxy and the WebShield scans all inbound and outbound traffic, does Avast scan the traffic locally or does it send everything to the Avast cloud through a proxy?

Comment: So my suspicion is indeed correct? Those numbers are your proxy which scans your traffic.

Comment: Yes, I guess so. The question remains whether the endpoint is a local process or on the cloud; and in the latter case, Avast is using half of my data quota. I will experiment with settings in the next few weeks and report on results.